# Python: Class as var dump error

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to make a VarDump class, where I can do:

```
vd.attribute = value
```

and

```
print vd.attribute
```

So, this is the code:

```
class VarDump:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dump={}

    def __setattr__(self,item,var):
        self.dump[item]=var

    def __getattr__(self,item):
        if not item in self.dump: return ""
        return self.dump[item]

vd = VarDump()
vd.foo="bar"
print vd.foo
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
File "classAsVarDump.py", line 9, in __getattr__
    if not item in self.dump: return ""
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Actually, if that's all you need, `class VarDump(object): pass` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.dump={}` calls `__setattr__` to set `dump`, which calls `__getattr__` to get the `dump` to put `dump` into, which calls `__getattr__` to get the `dump`, etc. You could resolve this with `object.__setattr__`, but the easier way is to just do this:

```
class Namespace(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return ''
```

`__getattr__` is only called when the attribute isn't found by normal means, so this doesn't need to handle looking up attributes that have actually been set.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.3, use the new [`types.SimpleNamespace()` type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) instead:

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> vd = SimpleNamespace()
>>> vd.foo = 'bar'
>>> print(vd.foo)
bar
```

The documentation gives you a backwards-compatible version on a platter:

```
class SimpleNamespace:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        keys = sorted(self.__dict__)
        items = ("{}={!r}".format(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in keys)
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(items))
```

The only difference between your version and this one is that this one doesn't use `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` (not needed at all), this version takes initial values in the initializer, and it includes a nice representation:

```
>>> vd
namespace(foo='bar')
```

Comment: Great, however I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: @NacibNeme: That's why I included the backwards-compatible Python version right here in the answer. It works directly on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

No need to override `__setattr__` or `__getattr__`

```
>>> class VarDump(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> c = VarDump()
>>> c.bar = 2
>>> print c.bar
2
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want they to be written to self.__dict__